# basic structure for converting ajax to axios?

Tags: ajax, reactjs, axios

Can some one give me example of how to convert ajax to axios ?
I am trying to convert this code into axios

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://example.com/storeauthcode',
    // Always include an `X-Requested-With` header in every AJAX request,
    // to protect against CSRF attacks.
    headers: {
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
    },
    contentType: 'application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8',
    success: function(result) {
        // Handle or verify the server response.
    },
    processData: false,
    data: authResult['code']
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
axios.post('http://example.com/storeauthcode', authResult['code'], {
   headers: {
      'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
      'Content-Type: 'application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8',
   },
   transformResponse: (data) => { // do something with your data },
});
```

However a better place for the `content-type` would be the axios instance config itself.

Answer (score 0):

Configure once globally:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

Then per request:

```
const result = await axios.post(
  'http://example.com/storeauthcode',
  authResult['code'],
  {
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8'
    }
  }
);
```